# Remove line from file after performing a match

Tags: powershell, csv

I am matching two files based on PersonID, and outputting to a third (ListAfinal). Essentially, I am adding the address and phone numbers for those entries that have it, and adding blank spaces for those who don't. I want to remove the lines from ListB that were matched to ListA, so after the matching we are left with a ListB with no matches in ListA.

```
$f1=(import-csv 'C:\Desktop\ListA.csv' -header FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, PersonID, Address, PhoneNumber)[1..999]
$f2=(import-csv 'C:\Desktop\ListB.csv' -header PersonID, Address, PhoneNumber)[1..999]
$f1|
   %{
      $PersonID=$_.PersonID
      $m=$f2|?{$_.PersonID -eq $PersonID}
      $_. Address=$m.Address
      $_. PhoneNumber=$m.PhoneNumber
    }
$f1 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 |  % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File 'C:\Desktop\ListAFinal.csv'
```

Every method I have found online does the line removal based off of a specific string, but in my case I just want to remove the line if it was matched. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a hashtable (a hashtable of hashtables actually) from your second CSV:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv 'C:\Desktop\ListB.csv' -Header PersonID, Address, PhoneNumber |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 999

$contacts = @{}
$csv1 | ForEach-Object {
  $contacts[$_.PersonID] = @{
    Address     = $_.Address
    PhoneNumber = $_.PhoneNumber
  }
}
```

Then use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding the information to the data from the first CSV:

```
$csv2 = Import-Csv 'C:\Desktop\ListA.csv' -Header FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, PersonID, Address, PhoneNumber |
  Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 999

$csv2 |
  Select-Object *, @{n='Address';e={$contacts[$_.PersonID]['Address']}},
    @{n='PhoneNumber';e={$contacts[$_.PersonID]['PhoneNumber']}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\Desktop\ListAFinal.csv' -NoType
```

Note that I ***strongly*** recommend ***against*** removing headers or quotes from your output CSV unless you have *very* compelling reasons to do so.

To remove records from `$csv2` that have a match in `$csv1` simply do this:

```
$IDs = $csv1 | Select-Object -Expand PersonID
$csv2 | Where-Object { $IDs -notcontains $_.PersonID }
```

Comment: This works much better than my code snippet above. However, after matching, your sample does not remove the lines from ListB that were "matched" to ListA.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! I did not occur to me to assign the action to variable, then set the condition against that variable. Thank you.